# How do I write function to convert a character vector to minutes?

Tags: r, function

I would like to write a function to convert a character vector in the "time_spent" column to a numeric vector of minutes.

```
#Import libraries
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

#Create dataframe
df <- data.frame(country = c("Russia", "China", "USA"),
                 time_spent = c("0:10", "1:20", "2:36"))

#Convert "time_spent" from factor to character
df$time_spent <- lapply(df$time_spent, as.character)
```

I can do this with the following code, but I want to learn how to write it as a function.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(minutes = paste(time_spent, "00", sep = ":"),
         minutes = hms(minutes),
         minutes = hour(minutes)*60 + minute(minutes))
```

I know I've butchered this function and its application, but I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

```
#Function to convert "time_spent" vector into minutes
convert_to_minutes <- function(x) {
  df$x = paste(x, "00", sep = ":") %>% 
  df$x = hms(x) %>% 
  df$x = hour(x)*60 + minute(x)
  }

#Apply function
df %>% 
  convert_to_minutes(df$time_spent)
```

**Related question 2**

How do I use `map` to apply my `convert_to_minutes` function to multiple `time_spent` vectors as in the following dataframe?

```
df2 <- data.frame(country = c("Russia", "China", "USA"),
                 time_spent = c("0:10", "1:20", "2:36"),
                 time_spent2 = c("0:15", "0:12", "1:47"),
                 time_spent3 = c("0:25", "3:45", "0:18"))
```

Comment: So `"1:20"` are `"HH:MM"`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few typos and syntax errors in your function. You can use -

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

convert_to_minutes <- function(x) {
  x = paste(x, "00", sep = ":") 
  x = lubridate::hms(x) 
  x = x@hour *60 + x@minute
  x
}

convert_to_minutes(df$time_spent)
#[1]  10  80 156
```

To apply it for multiple columns you can use `across` in `tidyverse` (or `lapply` in base R).

```
df2 %>%
  mutate(across(contains('time_spent'), convert_to_minutes))

#  country time_spent time_spent2 time_spent3
#1  Russia         10          15          25
#2   China         80          12         225
#3     USA        156         107          18
```

Comment: Thank you. There were all excellent answers in this thread, but I found this one the most intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

As you already use lubridate, you can make a more efficient use with it. Instead of using `lubridate::hms` it also supports `lubridate:hm`. Another handy function is `lubridate::as.duration` which allows you to format in any measures, which in your case is minutes. Then just convert the duration to numeric and you are done.

```
x <- c("0:10", "1:20", "2:36")
as.numeric(as.duration(hm(x)), "minutes")
# [1]  10  80 156
```

**Full answer to convert df2**

```
df2 <- data.frame(country = c("Russia", "China", "USA"),
                 time_spent = c("0:10", "1:20", "2:36"),
                 time_spent2 = c("0:15", "0:12", "1:47"),
                 time_spent3 = c("0:25", "3:45", "0:18"))

library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)

cols <- 2:length(names(df2))

df2[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(as.duration(hm(x)), "minutes")), .SDcols = cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

A function to convert to minutes, in base R only, could be the following.

```
convert_to_minutes <- function(x) {
  f <- function(x) as.vector(as.integer(x) %*% c(60, 1))
  y <- strsplit(as.character(x), ":")
  sapply(y, f)
}

y <- c("0:10", "1:20", "2:36")
convert_to_minutes(y)
#[1]  10  80 156
```

---

To convert a data.frame column, with `dplyr` function `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(minutes = convert_to_minutes(time_spent))
#  country time_spent minutes
#1  Russia       0:10      10
#2   China       1:20      80
#3     USA       2:36     156
```

To convert multiple columns, use `mutate(across(.))`.

```
df2 %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("time"), convert_to_minutes, .names = "minutes_{col}"))
#  country time_spent time_spent2 time_spent3 minutes_time_spent minutes_time_spent2 minutes_time_spent3
#1  Russia       0:10        0:15        0:25                 10                  15                  25
#2   China       1:20        0:12        3:45                 80                  12                 225
#3     USA       2:36        1:47        0:18                156                 107                  18
```

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg Give me a moment and I'll answer to the 2nd request.